# On autocomplete select, should display the ajax call response

Tags: ajax, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I am using autocomplete jquery function to get contents on a search box.

I'm doing one ajax call(**ajax1**) to get the contents for autocomplete the search box,

on select of any of the contents,I am doing one more ajax call(**ajax2**) to get another set of data based on the previous value selected.the data is getting populated ,but it gets displayed only on the click or keypress of the searchbox.
I want that automatically populated.Is there any way??
Also on key press of the searchbox,it is searching the contents populated in ajax2,this should be from contents ajax1.

Is there any way to solve this problem??

Code:

```
jQuery( "#Mobile" ).autocomplete({

     source: function(request, response) {
     jQuery.getJSON(ajax1, { term:request.term}, function(data){
        response(data);
        autocomplte_loading=false;
    });
  },
      highlightClass: "highlight",
      close:function(event,ui)
      {
        jQuery('.ui-autocomplete').html('');
      },
      response: function(event, ui) 
      { },
      select: function(event, ui) { 
        var selectedObj = ui.item;  
        jQuery('#Mobile').addClass('ui-autocomplete-loading');            
        autocomp_data = {datas};
        jQuery('input[name=Mobile]').val(selectedObj.id);
                   //     if(jQuery( "#Mobile" ).length >0) {
                        jQuery( "#Mobile" ).autocomplete({

                        source: function(request, response) {
                        jQuery.getJSON(ajax2, { "data"}, function(data){
                        response(data);
                        autocomplte_loading=true;
                       // jQuery("#Mobile").autocomplete('search',last_search_term); 
                        });
                        },
                        highlightClass: "highlight",
                        close:function(event,ui)
                        {
                        jQuery('.ui-autocomplete').html('');
                        },
                        response: function(event, ui) 
                        {},
                        select: function(event, ui) {

                        jQuery('#Mobile').addClass('ui-autocomplete-loading');            
                        autocomp_data = {selectedproject:selectedObj.id, project:selectedObj.value, location:selectedObj.location, datafromhome: true};
                        jQuery('input[name=Mobile]').val(selectedObj.id);                

                        }
                        }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
                        var $a = jQuery("<a class ='x' for='as' href='javaScript:void(0);' id='test'></a>").text(item.name);
                       // jQuery("#Mobile").append($a).appendTo(ul); 
                        return jQuery("<li></li>").append($a).appendTo(ul);

                        };
                          jQuery("#Mobile").autocomplete('search',last_search_term); 
        }
    }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
            var $a = jQuery("<a data-url='"+item.projecturl+"' data-id='"+item.id+"' data-label='"+item.label+"'></a>").text(item.label);
            var desired = this.term.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '');
            last_search_term=desired;
            highlightText(desired, $a);
            return jQuery("<li></li>").append($a).appendTo(ul);
        };
```

Comment: Please share your code too.

Comment: I've shared the code